# JMenu not appearing until window is resized

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenubar

I am trying to create a sample program that has a menu and some options on it.
The problem is When i run the program, the menu does not appear until the window is re-sized. I am not sure what the problem is and I would appreciate any help.

Here is the code that I am working with:

P.S. I already imported all of the libraries that I need.

```
public class TextEditor {


public static void main(String[] args) {
     JFrame f = new JFrame();

    f.setSize(700,500);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setResizable(true);
    f.setVisible(true);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    f.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");

    menuBar.add(file);

    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open File"); 

    file.add(open);

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting sizes and setting the JFrame visible **before** adding your JMenuBar, so it's no wonder that the menu bar is not showing initially since it is never rendered initially. Your solution is to add the JMenuBar **before** packing and visualizing your GUI and in this way your problem is solved.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextEditor {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame f = new JFrame("Foo");
      f.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(700, 500)));
      JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
      f.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
      JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
      file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
      menuBar.add(file);
      JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open File");
      file.add(open);

      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      f.pack();
      f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```